# matching multiple strings in a corpus

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I need to match a large number of strings on a corpus. However, the "strings" are not lists of characters, but vectors of objects of a class with custom overloaded == operator.

I decided to use [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) for the job. Unfortunately, I did not yet find any open source implementations of it, which would work with sequence containers (specifically vectors) of arbitrary objects. Fortunately, I found pretty neat [piece of code](http://www.komodia.com/aho-corasick/) here, which works well with ordinary strings. With some work, I could rewrite it as a template that would solve my problem.

But before doing that or writing the algorithm from scratch, I wanted to ask that do you know any library that already solves my problem?

Thanks in advance,

Timo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `basic_string<T>` it has all the methods of a string, but isn't restricted to characters.

Comment: This did the trick with pretty minimal modifications to my code and the code I was planning to rewrite. In my case it was easier than 'sth's suggestion as I could easily replace vector specific functionality such as 'push_back' with basic_string methods in my code. Also, the AC implementation I referred used strings only in a few initializations, so replacing them was also quite simple. Now I need to only test, if the resulting code is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `CSuffixTrie` class in the code you linked to contains two typedefs:

```
typedef std::wstring SearchString;
typedef wchar_t SearchChar;
```

If you replace those typedefs with your own types you should already be halfway there. You will need to implement an equivalent of `substr` on your vectors and maybe a few other string functions, but that shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Yep. This is something I was planning to do.